Kepler's measurements in solar system
I am interested in knowing that does Kepler measured distances in solar system or only relative distances to a astronomical unit which he doesn't know how long is it in our meters.

Suggestion to the post (v2): Consider to replace the word measured with the word calculated.

This is a question for history of science. but short: he only could measure relative distances, absolute distances were not know at his time (or just estimates)
